# Avatar using Mediapipe, Unity and Python

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, mediapipe, avatar

I want to make a 2d avatar (a simple emoji) in python with the help of python. Can anyone please drop an approach to do that?

When I started working on this, I found out that there's a library with the name mediapipe which allows you to capture a user's face landmarks and creates a facemesh. I now want to transfer the user's lip's expressions to the emoji's expressions.

Any help would be appreciated a lot! Thanks in advance.